# RegEx to extract a name after a string is found in a string

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I am trying to check if a string is in a string using RegEx in a AutoHotKey script.

If my string is a file path like this:

```
G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php
```

Then I need to extract the `webdevapp` part.

From the AutoHotKey docs it gives this example for a RegEx command that will store the found value to a variable:

```
; Returns 1 and stores "XYZ" in SubPat1.
FoundPos := RegExMatch("abcXYZ123", "abc(.*)123", SubPat)
```

So in theory something similar to this below except the regex part would need to be changed...

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch("G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php", "G:\htdocs\projects\(.*)\app\folder\file.php", DomainNameVar)
```

Any help in extracting that domain name from the file path into a variable in AutoHotKey?

It basically need to check if the string starts with `G:\htdocs\projects\` and if it does then grab any character after that point until it comes up to the next `\`

Comment: I'm not familiar with AuthoHotKey. What is the result for `FoundPos := RegExMatch("G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php", "G:\htdocs\projects\(.*)\app\folder\file.php", DomainNameVar)  ` (you might want to include that into the question for reference). In many systems "\"  might be a special character, so you might want to try `FoundPos := RegExMatch("G:\\htdocs\\projects\\webdevapp\\app\\folder\\file.php", "G:\\htdocs\\projects\\(.*)\\app\\folder\\file.php", DomainNameVar)`

Comment: @Attilio I will update the question as this part  `\app\folder\file.php` should not be in the regex as it will be different for each string.  I gort this regex test to match everything up until the end of the string I need if I can just get the result to remove the first part from it `G:\\htdocs\\projects\\[^\\]*` matches `G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp` on this string `G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php` demo - https://regex101.com/r/rFQRbT/1

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch("G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php", "G:\\htdocs\\projects\\([^\\]+)*", DomainNameVar) 

G:\\htdocs\\projects\\([^\\]+)*
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/rFQRbT/1